# Namespace do facebook não funcionam no JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, facebook, namespace

Estou usando jsf pessoal, estou tentando fazer o facebook reconhecer minhas metatags:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<h:head>
<title><ui:insert name="title-principal"></ui:insert></title>
<ui:insert name="head-meta-principal" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/logocab.png"/>

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxx" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph META Tags"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="David Walsh Blog"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.latterpage.com/login"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.latterpage.com/resources/images/126DIARIO_DAYBOOK.png"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="450"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="298"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Facebook's Open Graph protocol allows for web developers to turn their websites into Facebook "/>
```

Porém, quando vou testar no [debug do facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) 
com a [url do meu site](http://www.latterpage.com),
ele me retorna esse erro:

> fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( 966242223397117 ) will be assigned.

Parece que ele não reconhece as tags, como posso resolver?

Comment: Coloca o código da sua página. Assim fica melhor para te ajudar

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Namespace facebook não funciona JSF](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110535/namespace-facebook-n%c3%a3o-funciona-jsf)

Comment: Minha nossa..! Você tá duplicando pergunta a torto e direito... Se puder dar uma conferida tipo rápida na [help], vai ver qual é a pauta mínima pra trabalhar aqui, não tem mistério mas pode esquecer essa trip fórum ;)

Comment: Amigo todos veem aqui procurando ajuda, escrever alguem poderia me ajuda é redundante e de nada agrega a duvida. Faça titulos intuitivos e não duplique pergunta, aqui é comunitário, ficar duplicando não vai te trazer respostas mais rápidas. Espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Se uma futura pergunta vier a ser fechada é por um motivo bom, o que você deve fazer é corrigir os problemas na pergunta e aguardar ela ser reaberta e não duplica-la.

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema não tem nada a ver com o servidor ou JSF.

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer para verificar o que ocorre é olhar o código-fonte da página online. Fiz isso e as tags estão lá corretamente.

Portanto, o problema está em algum ponto relacionado com o script do Facebook. Não quero dizer que ele está com algum erro, mas que provavelmente sua configuração não está adequada.

Verifique se você não está colocando o script do Facebook em algum frame, onde o documento não tem a tag `meta`.

Verifique também se esses dados estão corretos, afinal me parece que você copiou as tags de algum site tal como do "David Walsh Blog". Note que você não pode simplesmente copiar as tags de qualquer lugar. Veja a [documentação do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) para como fazer este tipo de integração. No caso do App ID, você precisa ter seu site configurado de acordo com o ID do seu [dashborard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/89000000000000/dashboard).